Wi-Fi adapter gets disabled automatically after system reboot
I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 10, dual boot. My Wi-Fi adapter gets disabled after this. After some online research I have disabled the device (Realtek 802.11 adapter) and enabled it again and then rebooted the system: this fixes the issue and enables the WiFi. But if I go to Ubuntu in dual boot and then come back to Windows, the WiFi adapter gets disabled again. Also, system is taking more than usual time to boot into Windows. So, I have to enable the device manually every time I boot to Windows after Ubuntu. WiFi is working well on Ubuntu.
I have disabled the secure boot and fast boot but it is not working
